# Confusion with partial derivatives with respect to composition function.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Consier $$F=F(V,T,N(N_-,N_+)),$$

Why we can derive:
$$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N_-}\right)_{V,T,N}=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N_{-}}\right)_{V, T, N_{+}}+\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N_{+}}\right)_{V, T, N_{-}} \frac{\mathrm{d} N_{+}}{\mathrm{d} N_{-}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, removing the extra variables and $\pm$ subscripting, we have something in the form of: $$\left(\dfrac{\partial f(z(x,y))}{\partial x}\right)_{z(x,y)}=\left(\dfrac{\partial [f\circ z](x,y)}{\partial x}\right)_y+\left(\dfrac{\partial [f\circ z](x,y)}{\partial y}\right)_x\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}$$
Where as when $g(x,z):=k(x,h(x,z))$ the chain rule says:$$\left(\dfrac{\partial g(x,z)}{\partial x}\right)_{z}=\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial k(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)_y+\left(\dfrac{\partial k(x,y))}{\partial y}\right)_x\left(\dfrac{\partial h(x,z)}{\partial x}\right)_{z}\right]_{y:=h(x,z)}$$ Thus... if we interpret $\tfrac {\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=\left(\tfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_{z}$ , it appears to just be the chain rule in confusing disguise.